# What is the standard team composition for a conquest game?

Tags: smite

I'm very new to Smite, and I'm wondering if there is some kind of standard team composition in high level play, comparable to the top, jungle, mid, dual lane meta in LoL.

What are the roles, and where should they go to start the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smite has 5 roles, each specializing in "the usual moba fit", but some cases offering more. The main conquest map has 3 lanes and a jungle. Lanes are **Short, Mid, and Long** as defined by distance between towers.

1. ***Guardian*** - Generally the tanks in the game. they can take a beating and support the team with lots of CC abilities. However, there are damage oriented guardians (Hades, Ares, Athena) that can also be just as threatening as the other damage dealing roles. **Guardians are usually in the long lane with the Hunter**
2. ***Hunter*** - The ranged damage dealer of the team. Generally needs the help of Guardian's CC to secure many kills. There are hunters with good survivability like Nieth, Ah Muzen Cab, and Cupid that they can fend for themselves in the short lane as well. **Hunters are mainly in the long lane with Guardians**
3. ***Assassin*** - Assassins spend most of their time in the jungle and gank(ambush) enemies who are out of place to deal lots of damage very quickly. Some Assassins can partner up with Warriors in the short lane, or Guardians in the Long lane to be beneficial as well. **Assassins Jungle**
4. ***Warrior*** - Kind of a mixture between Assassins and Guardians. They hit pretty hard, but can also take a beating. Warriors are often solo in the short lane or with the Assassin. They are designed to be the "jack of all trades, master of none". **Warriors generally solo the short lane**
5. ***Mage*** - A mixture between Hunter and Assassin, mages deal incredible damage at range, but are very very squishy. Some mages (Aphrodite, Chang'e, and Hel) work well in the short lane helping the Warrior with their incredible healing capabilities and generally build/work as Guardians instead. **Mages spend their time solo in Mid lane**

The current most common meta is 1-1-2 with Jungler. I have seen different games where 2-1-2, and 1-2-1 with jungle work as well though. It boils down to teamwork, awareness, and  knowing your role.

Comment: TO add to this, I find that certain warriors make perfect hunter babysitters as well, especially ones with a decent amount of CC and an ability to heal themselves to consistently soak up damage.

Comment: As the game's meta is extremely volatile (probably more so since the warrior rework that released today) This answer is merely a guideline of what the roles are intended/designed for, not everything they are capable of... I have seen Jungle Ymirs... and it works... stupidly