# Which lane shall I choose in which case?

Tags: smite

I'd like to know more about the lane thing in Smite. I'm quite a MOBA noob and I never really understood the concept of the "who goes which lane?" concept. Could you enlighten me a little about that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Conquest, there are three lanes: middle, long, and short. The two outside lanes have a different distance between the middle towers, which is how you can tell them apart. Unlike other MOBAs, they aren't always on the same side of the minimap. Depending on which side of the map you start on, long could be either left or right; the minimap will rotate so that your starting base is always at the bottom and the enemy base is at the top.

The roles in a game of Smite, as far as the metagame is concerned, give information about what your goal in game is, and where you should be playing. These loosely correspond to the god type.

Here's some information about how each role should treat the early-mid game to get you started.

**ADC**: Pretty much always a Hunter, this player starts the game by taking the attack speed buff (purple), then goes to the long lane and farms. He stays in the long lane, farming, and grabbing the attack speed buff whenever it respawns. He will also go with his team for early-mid game gold fury objectives, since that helps his farm.

**Support**: Usually a Guardian, although some others work as well. This player starts by helping his mid and ADC get their buffs, then hangs out in the long lane with the ADC for a little while before roaming mid and taking some of the jungle camps. The support will help gank for the ADC and mid, but generally doesn't cross mid into the other side of the map.

**Mid**: Usually Mages will play mid, although there is a little variation. The mid takes the attack damage buff (red), then goes to the mid lane. This player can shove his lane (kill all the minions quickly) and then go to either long or short as a "rotation" to help the players there and get some kills. If you can shove your lane harder than your opponent (or outright kill your lane opponent), you can get an advantage.

**Jungle**: You will usually find assassins in the jungle. The jungler starts by taking the speed buff (yellow), then helping the solo laner take the mana buff and going to short with the solo laner for a few waves. Then the jungler goes into the jungle and kills neutral camps, and helps to gank all three lanes.

**Solo**: The solo laner can be any god type, so long as they have decent sustain (the ability to stay out of base for a long time, usually through healing) and skirmishing (basic 1v1 combat ability). Warriors are usually a good fit, although there are characters in any role that can play solo. The goal here is to farm.  You're generally going to be alone for most of the early-mid game, with your solo enemy, facing each other down and farming.

Comment: Could you add some info about non-guardian gods with support abilities like Aphrodite and Hel? I'd assume they're the "some others work as well" you mention in the support section, but I'm not too sure. I know in other MOBAs, their types are usually explicitly listed as support, but in Smite they're usually listed as mage (although I can think of 3 non-mage healers).

Comment: @Ellesedil I know Guan Yu is also played as support sometimes. I think that's a big enough topic for another entire question, however. Something like "What qualities make a good support?" or "How can I tell whether a character will be a good support?" It's outside the scope of this question/answer.

Comment: just to add on, the tried-and-true / pro / "meta" strategies that people use in Conquest can be very in depth and interesting to take a look at. There are specific strategies for what classes, characters, and combinations of characters fare best in each lane. There is also a heavy emphasis on rotation between lanes, meaning knowing when to leave your lane and switch to another for various reasons. Here is another [good question about Smite](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/165838/108888) with an answer that talks more about it (and was asked by StrixVaria, just by coincidence!)